# It's possible to replace existing html code with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Example current html code

```
<a rel="tag" title="see questions tagged 'php'" href="/tags/php/" class="tag-link-php">php</a>
```

I want use jQuery to replace it to be

```
<a href="http://php.net/"><img src="/images/tags/php.gif" height="16" width="16" alt="php" /></a><a rel="tag" title="see questions tagged 'php'" href="/tags/php/" class="tag-link-php">php</a>
```

Let me know

Comment: Can you clarify what you're asking here?  I can't see what exactly it is that you want to do and what the more general set of transformations you want is.

Comment: @templatetypedef 4 persons answer my question and it's a question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems to me that you want to put the following code

```
<a href="http://php.net/"><img src="/images/tags/php.gif" height="16" width="16" alt="php" /></a>
```

before any links with the class `tag-link-php`.  You can use the [`before`](http://api.jquery.com/before/) function for this:

```
$('a.tag-link-php').before('<a href="http://php.net/"><img src="/images/tags/php.gif" height="16" width="16" alt="php" /></a>');
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like:

```
$("<a/>", { 
   "href":  "http://www.php.net"
}).append($("<img>", {
   "src":    "/images/tags/php.gif",
   "height": "16",
   "width":  "16",
   "alt":    "/images/tags/php.gif"
})).insertBefore(".tag-link-php");
```

Answer (score 1):

You  can also use replaceWith:

http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

Answer (score 1):

Replace whole element / elements:

http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

Or just change some attributes:

http://api.jquery.com/attr/